# PHP & jQuery sending duplicate copies of email messages

Tags: php, email

I am trying to figure out why my users are receiving duplicate copies of email messages being sent from my web application.  Here is the code which sends the email:

```
function _send_user_email($to, $subject, $message) {
    $this->load->library('email');
    $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';    
    $config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->from('support@mysite.com', 'Customer Service');
    $this->email->reply_to('support@mysite.com', 'Customer Service');
    $this->email->to($to);
    $this->email->bcc('support@mysite.com');
    $this->email->subject($subject);
    $this->email->message($message);
    $this->email->send();
    if ( ! $this->email->send())
    {
        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
        exit;
    } 
}
```

Is there anything wrong with this code that might be causing the message to be sent twice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obviously, because of

```
$this->email->send();
    if ( ! $this->email->send())
```

You are sending email twice. Remove the first call, leave only the one in `if` statement

Comment: even if it's inside a `if` it WILL send the email, then check if it was success or not! So yup, you need to remove the 1st send.

Comment: Thanks for these comments.  It seems fairly unanimous that the error is the first call.  But I don't understand what is happening here.  What is happening here?  I see the first line actually sends the email message, but I guess I am not really understanding the syntax of:  if ( ! $this->email->send())

Comment: First line is sending the email and returns (i guess) `boolean` whether email is sent or not. Since you didn't save it to any variable, that value is ignored. Then second line is again sending the email, but this time you are checking the return value in `if` statement to see if the email was actually sent